# How do I target children of a "for" loop which creates a mesh, outside of the loop

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I'm trying to target every mesh created by one loop inside an another.

I have a loop inside another loop, a first that creates these spheres radially, inside another repeating these rows by incrementing the number of spheres each time the circle of sphere is growing.

I tried to increment a variable to have a continual number (1,2,3,4,5…) even if the loop start again, because the idea is to add each sound of my php array to each mesh that created, but I don't know if I need to do it inside the loop, or how to do it outside the loop?

```
  var mathpi = Math.PI/180;
  var startRadians = startAngle + mathpi;
  var arraysamples = <?php echo json_encode($samples);?>;
  var rangee = Math.round((Object.keys(arraysamples).length) / 5);
  var incrementAngle = 360/totalson;
  var incrementRadians = incrementAngle * mathpi;
  var totalson = 5;
  var yp = 30;


      for ( var n = 0; n < rangee; n ++) {
        for ( var i = 0; i < totalson; i ++ ) {

            var object = new THREE.Mesh( sphere, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } ) );

            var xp = centerX + Math.sin(startRadians) * radius;
            var zp = centerZ + Math.cos(startRadians) * radius;
            object.position.z = xp;
            object.position.x = zp;
            object.position.y = yp;

            nomsample ++;
            scene.add( object );
            startRadians += incrementRadians;
        }

        totalson = totalson + 3;
        var nomsample = totalson + 2;
        radius = radius + 100;
        startAngle = startAngle + 150;
        var startRadians = startAngle + mathpi;
        var incrementAngle = 360/totalson;
        var incrementRadians = incrementAngle * mathpi;

        if (yp > 59) {
            yp = yp - 30;
        } else {
            yp = yp + 30;
        }
      }
```

and the idea is to have something like :

```
for ( var i = 0; i < arraysamples.length ; i ++ ) {

          var sound[i] = new THREE.PositionalAudio(listener);
                  audioLoader.load('sounds/'arraysamples[1]'', function (buffer) {

                    sound[i].setBuffer(buffer);
                    sound[i].setRefDistance(20);
                    sound[i].play();
                    sound[i].setLoop(true);
                    sound[i].setVolume(1);
                });
           object.add(sound[i]);
      }
```

I just expect to add every sound of the array distribute to one mesh, with no several mesh with the same sound. I really hope I'm clear.
Thank you for taking time to read my problem and I apologize in advance if the problem seems simple.